# Merging Dict in python with similar keys

Tags: python

```
data1 = {'Height': {'Ajay': 145.830651784016,
  'Bist': 145.91779226416696,
  'Kay': 146.16402145150246}
}
 
data2 = {'Height': {'Kim': 155.830651784016,
  'DDD': 155.91779226416696,
  'Arambh': 156.16402145150246}
}

data3 = {'Height': {'Dong': 165.830651784016,
  'Ding': 165.91779226416696,
  'Dumba': 166.16402145150246}
}
```

Above are the 3 dictionary I wish to merge into one.
Below is expected output:

```
den_w = {'Height': {'Ajay': 145.830651784016,
      'Bist': 145.91779226416696,
      'Kay': 146.16402145150246,
      'Kim': 155.830651784016,
      'DDD': 155.91779226416696,
      'Arambh': 156.16402145150246,
      'Dong': 165.830651784016,
      'Ding': 165.91779226416696,
      'Dumba': 166.16402145150246}
        }
```

Below are my attempts. None reach expected output:

Failed Attempt 1:

```
den_w = {**data1, **data2, **data3}
```

Failed Attempt 2:

```
den_w = {k: [data1.get(k, {}), data2.get(k, {}), data3.get(k, {})] for k in data1.keys() | data2.keys() | data3.keys()}
```

Failed Attempt 3:

```
dicts = data1,data2,data3
```

Failed Attempt 4:

```
dicts = {}
dicts.update(data1)
dicts.update(data2)
dicts.update(data3)
```

Any way to reach expected output

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT: An approach using only ChainMap**

Here is a one-liner to do this. It groups and combines the sub-dicts for each unique key in your dictionaries.

```
from collections import ChainMap

L = [data1, data2, data3]

{k:dict(ChainMap(*[i.get(k) for i in L])) for k in dict(ChainMap(*L)).keys()}
```

```
{'Height': {'Dong': 165.830651784016,
  'Ding': 165.91779226416696,
  'Dumba': 166.16402145150246,
  'Kim': 155.830651784016,
  'DDD': 155.91779226416696,
  'Arambh': 156.16402145150246,
  'Ajay': 145.830651784016,
  'Bist': 145.91779226416696,
  'Kay': 146.16402145150246}}
```

Testing on a demo case -

```
d1 = {'a':{'x':1, 'y':2}, 'b':{'l':1, 'm':2}}
d2 = {'a':{'i':1, 'j':2}, 'b':{'w':1, 'z':2}}

L = [d1, d2]

{k:dict(ChainMap(*[i.get(k) for i in L])) for k in dict(ChainMap(*L)).keys()}
```

```
#dictionaries for key a and b are respectively combined
{'a': {'i': 1, 'j': 2, 'x': 1, 'y': 2}, 
 'b': {'w': 1, 'z': 2, 'l': 1, 'm': 2}}
```

---

Here is a pythonic way to do this using `collections.defaultdict` and `collections.ChainMap`. I have explained the steps below.

```
from collections import ChainMap, defaultdict

L = [data1, data2, data3]
d = defaultdict(dict)

for key in dict(ChainMap(*L)).keys():
    for i in L:
        d[key].update(i.get(key))

d = dict(d)
print(d)
```

```
{'Height': {'Dong': 165.830651784016,
  'Ding': 165.91779226416696,
  'Dumba': 166.16402145150246,
  'Kim': 155.830651784016,
  'DDD': 155.91779226416696,
  'Arambh': 156.16402145150246,
  'Ajay': 145.830651784016,
  'Bist': 145.91779226416696,
  'Kay': 146.16402145150246}}
```

1. `defaultdict(dict)` stores a dict of dicts
2. `dict(ChainMap(*L)).keys()` fetches the unique keys that exist across all the dictionaries in the list. In this case its just `height`
3. For each `key` and for each element in the list, the key's dictionary is updated with the values for that `key`.
4. Convert this d to `dict`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def merge(a, b):
    for key in b:
        if key in a:
            if isinstance(a[key], dict) and isinstance(b[key], dict):
                merge(a[key], b[key])
            elif a[key] == b[key]:
                pass             
        else:
            a[key] = b[key]
    return a

den_w  = merge(data1, data2)
den_w = merge(den_w, data3)
```

Output:

```
{'Height': {'Ajay': 145.830651784016,
  'Arambh': 156.16402145150246,
  'Bist': 145.91779226416696,
  'DDD': 155.91779226416696,
  'Ding': 165.91779226416696,
  'Dong': 165.830651784016,
  'Dumba': 166.16402145150246,
  'Kay': 146.16402145150246,
  'Kim': 155.830651784016}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Find the common keys between all the dicts and then merge them

```
{k: {**data1[k], **data2[k], **data3[k]} 
 for k in set(data1.keys()).intersection(
     set(data2.keys())).intersection(set(data3.keys()))}
```

Output:

```
{'Height': {'Ajay': 145.830651784016,
  'Arambh': 156.16402145150246,
  'Bist': 145.91779226416696,
  'DDD': 155.91779226416696,
  'Ding': 165.91779226416696,
  'Dong': 165.830651784016,
  'Dumba': 166.16402145150246,
  'Kay': 146.16402145150246,
  'Kim': 155.830651784016}}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `update` method merges dictionaries, e.g.

```
dicts = {}
dicts.update(data1)
dicts.update(data2)
dicts.update(data3)
```

This will create a new dictionary with the union of the data (later updates replace earlier ones, just as one would expect). This is what one can call a "shallow" merge, i.e. it just merges the top level keys.

To merge the entire trees of keys, the problem becomes nontrivial and there are a lot of different ways to interpret a deep merge. The [deepmerge](https://pypi.org/project/deepmerge/) package implements some of these strategies, i.e.

```
dicts = {}
merge_strategy.merge(dicts, data1)
```

Comment: Did you tried this answer? IT DOESN'T WORK!

Comment: It does, but it depends on what you are looking for. It is hard to give complete answer in general but I added some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need a fully generic solution, the following approach might suffice:

```
data1 = {'Height': {'Ajay': 145.830651784016,
  'Bist': 145.91779226416696,
  'Kay': 146.16402145150246}
}
 
data2 = {'Height': {'Kim': 155.830651784016,
  'DDD': 155.91779226416696,
  'Arambh': 156.16402145150246}
}

data3 = {'Height': {'Dong': 165.830651784016,
  'Ding': 165.91779226416696,
  'Dumba': 166.16402145150246}
}

den_w = data1.copy() 
den_w['Height'].update(data2['Height'])
den_w['Height'].update(data3['Height'])

print(den_w)
```

Giving you:

```
{'Height': {'Ajay': 145.830651784016,
        'Bist': 145.91779226416696,
        'Kay': 146.16402145150246,
        'Kim': 155.830651784016,
        'DDD': 155.91779226416696,
        'Arambh': 156.16402145150246,
        'Dong': 165.830651784016,
        'Ding': 165.91779226416696,
        'Dumba': 166.16402145150246}
}
```

If you are using Python 3.9, this could also be:

```
den_w = data1.copy() 
den_w['Height'] |= data2['Height'] | data3['Height']
```